# Menu Item with JavaScript

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

The Abp documentation describes how the menu's associated JavaScript files are  automatically generated by the framework based on NavigationProvider class.

My question is: has anyone tried extending the `abp.nav.menus` JavaScript files produced on the client-side?

If so, would you able to provide a code snippet(s) on how to assist?

My intention is to create a menu item that execute a JavaScript function rather than url, which redirect to a new page.  For example, to open a modal dialog box on top of existing page.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with JQuery. Enter # for the menu link and set click with JQuery.

```
$($("#leftsidebar .menu ul li a")[2]).click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location = "https://www.google.com";
});
```

[image]